# Is there a way to view a javascript object as JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

In my web application, there is a complex JavaScript object that I need to debug. I'd like to be able to view it in it's JSON form. It is not sent to or from the server, so I can't see it in the network tab of any of the developer tools. I can see it in the "Scope Variables" area, but not as JSON.

Is there a way, using the developer tools for any of the major browsers, to view a local JavaScript variable as JSON?

Comment: Do you really need a huge JSON string or just `console.log(yourobject)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)
```

Although you can display objects directly in most debuggers using

```
console.log(obj);
```

or

```
console.dir(obj);
```

Comment: And if you add the third `indent` parameter (number of spaces) the output will be more readable, e.g. `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)`.

Comment: What worked the best in Chrome was to combine these approaches. I used: console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));

Comment: i always use a tab for argument #3: JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t") which makes it line-up better imho...

Answer (score 1):

In chrome or in firebug, simply do `console.log(myObj)`  You will be able to open up the object and see its values and properties.